# How to unhook or remove function from selector below a certain viewport size

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm sure this question has been asked and answered, but I can't find the correct terms to search to find it. I am using the slimmenu jquery plugin which has a pretty simple initialization.

```
$('#navigation').slimmenu({});
```

I am using this on my navigation menu and that's working fine. I want it to only activate at 768px or below and deactivate above 768px. The activation is working fine, but if I size back up over 768px, it's still active. I'm not sure how to remove or unbind it.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).on("load resize", function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 769) { // only run if 768 or less
        $('.nav.main-nav').addClass('slimmenu'); // add class to nav to trigger responsive nav
        $('.nav.main-nav.slimmenu').slimmenu({ // responsive nav function
        });
    }
    else {
    }
}); // end on load resize
```

It's the "else" portion I can't seem to get to work. I've tried a number of things including
1) removing the "slimmenu" class
2) unbind(), off(), remove(), detach()

The plugin adds semantic markup when activated and I need that removed when it's unactivated because it messes up the styling when the nav menu isn't in use. I don't know how to "undo" the slimmenu function, if there is indeed a way.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS media queries to alter styles?

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
            .yourClass {
                       //styles to apply at 768px or below
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could hide and style those elements back the way they were with CSS, but I would rather have the markup removed rather than adding more styling. I didn't know if there was a way to undo a function.

Comment: You could try .toggleClass() instead of .addClass()
on there website it says that this is the way to use there plugin
$('#navigation').slimmenu(
{
    resizeWidth: '800',
    collapserTitle: 'Main Menu',
    animSpeed: 'medium',
    easingEffect: null,
    indentChildren: false,
    childrenIndenter: '&nbsp;'
});

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I tried the toggleClass and it does remove/add the class appropriately, but the extra markup is still there. I've gone through their list of options, but unfortunately, none of them cover this. Thanks!